# GO making multiple goroutines that use nmap

Tags: go

I'm trying to use Go's concurrency to create a script that runs multiple nmap scans with different options but whenever I try to run the program it exits after the 1st nmap scan completes. Is there a way to prevent this?

here's the code:

```
package main

import (
    "syscall"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "fmt"
)
func main(){
    args1 := []string{"nmap","-sS","127.0.0.1"}
    args2 := []string{"nmap","-sN","127.0.0.1"}
    args3 := []string{"nmap","-sV","127.0.0.1"}

    go funccmd(args1)

    go funccmd(args2)

    go funccmd(args3)

    fmt.Scanln()

}

func funccmd(args []string){
    env := os.Environ()

    cmdpath, runErr := exec.LookPath("/usr/bin/nmap")
    if runErr != nil {
        panic(runErr)
    }   

    execErr := syscall.Exec(cmdpath, args, env)
    if execErr != nil {
        panic(execErr)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use syscall.Exec. That calls execve which replaces the current program with nmap. Use exec.Cmd to execute nmap instead.

Comment: I get an error: cmd.Run() failed with exec: "nmap -sS 127.0.0.1": executable file not found in $PATH
exit status 1
which i assume its because go can't find the path to nmap so how do i resolve this?

Comment: Did you use exec.Command to initialize Cmd? That looks at the path. If you initialized the fields manually, use exec.Command.